# Django HttpResponse "expected a bytes-like object, str found"

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the above TypeError from a healthcheck route on Django 3.1.2 on python 3.6.

The full error logged is:

```
ERROR 2020-11-02 18:32:32,046 /home/centos/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/log.py log_response Internal Server Error: /healthcheck/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/centos/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/centos/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 116, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/home/centos/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 113, in process_response
    response['Content-Length'] = str(len(response.content))
  File "/home/centos/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 315, in content
    return b''.join(self._container)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, str found
```

That error is raised every time the route is requested. The full view definition is:

```
def healthcheck_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse("OK", content_type="text/plain")
    return response
```

What on earth have I done??

Comment: seems like `sentry_sdk` is causing the exception. How does your settings.py look like?

Comment: Yes, it does. My settings.py looks like... a whole bunch of commercially sensitive stuff I can't post here... :(, but Sentry sdk init looks basically identical to https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/guides/django/configuration/options/

Comment: at least, you must add a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example),

Comment: What on earth is in your settings.py :D

Answer (score 0):

<s>Upgrade sentry_sdk:</s>

```
# version 0.19.1 sentry_sdk.integrations.django.middleware:
                # Necessary for Django 3.1
                sentry_wrapped_method.__self__ = old_method.__self__  # type: ignore
```

Edit

To trigger this exact exception do this:

```py
def health_check_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse("OK", content_type="text/plain")
    response._container = ["OK"]
    return response
```

Are you sure you're running Django 3.1?

Looks like the else clause is missing in your HttpResponse.content:

```py
        if hasattr(value, '__iter__') and not isinstance(value, (bytes, str)):
            content = b''.join(self.make_bytes(chunk) for chunk in value)
            if hasattr(value, 'close'):
                try:
                    value.close()
                except Exception:
                    pass
        else:
            content = self.make_bytes(value)
```

Should be fixable by doing `HttpResponse(b"OK", content_type="text/plain")`, but if you're convinced you're running 3.1, I'd dig deeper.

Comment: Hi - thanks, but I'm already running sentry 1.19.1. I've also removed Sentry entirely - it's not related to Sentry. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I'm not convinced we're looking at the root cause. This is starting in the exception handler, which doesn't get triggered until a view causes one, but we don't see the view function called in the traceback.

Comment: Hi - no, I'm not either. The error looks like it's something that would affect every route, but that's the only one affected. The whole site, admin, logging, everything, seems otherwise perfectly fine. And I've changed the route to `return render(request, "core/healthcheck.html")` and it's __still returning the exact same error__. It's bizarre.

Comment: Sounds like a stupid question, but are you sure you're modifying the correct code? Uncomment the bit urls.py and now it should return a 404. If not, your view function isn't even called, but something else is matching.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I eventually "resolved" this by nuking the whole root dir and reinstalling, after which I couldn't reproduce the error. I'm still unable to explain what the cause was, but I suspect it's something that (a) I did wrong, and (b) is immediately obvious after the fact. Thanks for the help anyway.